# Sherlock : android:textAllCaps requires API level 14 (current min is 8)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Hello I am using the `Sherlock` library to achieve the `ActionBarTabs` in Android application but I see that it is setting text of `ActionBarTabs` to all caps so I am doing this so to set the text as regular.

```
<style name="My.TabText.Style" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:ellipsize">none</item> -->
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
</style>
```

but I am getting error message that `android:textAllCaps requires API level 14 (current min is 8)`. How I can resolve this so that it would work for all android version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the style to a `style-v14` folder and another without this value on the normal `style` folder.

Comment: "another without this value on the normal style folder" - but here again it will make my text to CAPITAL then How I can make this such that text will not be in caps to all android version

Comment: it won't make it to capital, because in previous APIs there's no such methods `setAllCaps()` for the framework to call.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to your ActionBarSherlock library the one that your implement in you project as a library
and go to this class.

```
com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.CapitalizingButton
```

inside that class you need to change this lines.

```
mAllCaps = appearance.getBoolean(R_styleable_TextAppearance_textAllCaps, true);


if (SANS_ICE_CREAM && mAllCaps && text != null)
```

**to**

```
mAllCaps = false;

if (SANS_ICE_CREAM && text != null)
```

What it is doing is that it is changing the default value of `android:textAllCaps` to `false` its kinda hack to the class

Comment: I did same which you suggested but still all text are caps

Comment: @Williams try not changing the if clause.. Put back the mAllCaps in there

Comment: @Williams how about removing all the if clause and its content.. Just the else clause remain.. If clause is the one that make the text capslock

Comment: @Williams i knew it ahahaha. +1 this post if it helps :))